# Include PDF with small page size

Tags: pdfpages, external-files

I want to include an external PDF in my document. The PDF looks like [this](https://www.docdroid.net/kbl3YRF/bibb.pdf.html) (except not redacted). As you can see, the last page is smaller than the others. Using `\includepdf` with pdfpages, the last page's content has been centered on a normal size page. I want the pages to appear in the document as they are in the pdf.

Comment: So you want the page sizes in your latex document to be the same as in the external pdf, correct?  This can be done, but it would take me a while to figure out how.

Comment: @JPi Yeah so let's say the external PDF is included as pages 5-7 in the latex document. Then I want page 5 to be identical - including page size - to external page 1, page 6 identical to external page 2, page 7 identical to external page 3. And naturally the rest of the document pages should be unaffected by the external PDF. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103219/14103) help in any manner? I tried various options, including noautoscale, offset, with pdfpages, no luck.

Comment: It's in the manual; see my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}

\includepdf[page=1,fitpaper]{mooi}
\includepdf[page=2,fitpaper]{mooi}
\end{document}
```

*EDIT*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1,2}
 {\includepdf[page=\x,fitpaper]{mooi}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That means you need include one page at a time. Is there any way to do this automatically while you include the whole document in one go?

Comment: I haven't tried with multiple pages.   Try it.  If that doesn't work then you can just use a for loop.

Comment: No, it does not work with multiple pages. Each page gets shifted to bottom with empty spaces at the top.

Comment: edited, see above

Comment: Nice! I'd like to add that for longer pdfs, this works: `\foreach \x in {1,...,167}`